# 19.10: I can't turn off suspend when I close my laptop screen

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop

Ubuntu Version 19.10
Trying to simply run Netflix from my laptop, project my screen onto the TV, and be able to shut my laptop lid without throwing the system into suspend.

I've turned off my suspend settings and also installed tweaks to turn off suspend while the lid is closed, but I still cannot shut the lid without the TV screen going blank.

How may I troubleshoot this?